# C++ Stand-alone executable

Tags: c++, linux, file

I'm writing a program in C++ that requires a file to be in the current directory, but I want to distribute it as one executable. Love2D uses a distribution method for games where you create a `.love` file and use `cat` to combine the `love2d` binary and your `.love` file (eg. `cat love2d awesomegame.love > awesomegame`). How can I write my program so it can use the information at the end of itself, and extract that out into a file.

**--- Update ---**

Thanks to all the wonderful help from @Dawid, I have got this working in a cleaner method than I originally suggested (see my answer if you want to do it that way). Here is my final source code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "ncat.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    ofstream ofile("ncat.exe", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
    for (unsigned long i = 0 ; i < ncat_exe_len; ++i) ofile << ncat_exe[i];
    ofile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the (binary) file I'm using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/21wps8usaqgthah/ncat.exe?dl=0

Comment: Very, *very* carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `xxd` tool. It can dump binary as hex in C style include header.

eg.

```
> echo test > a
> xxd -i a > a.h
> cat a.h
unsigned char a[] = {
  0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x0a
};
unsigned int a_len = 5;
```

then simply include header and use `a` and `a_len`.

Example:

before build:

```
xxd -i _file_name_ > _file_name_.h
```

in program:

```
#include "_file_name_.h"
void foo() {
    std::ofstream file ("output.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    file << _file_name_; // I believe the array will be named after source file
}
```

Comment: How do I use that in my program?

Comment: @Person: By writing `a[]` to file?

Comment: I thought the program would use the variable a as stringstream.

Comment: This is great, except names beginning with an underscore are reserved and this a variable definition technically doesn't belong to a header file because you can't include that into multiple translation units that are to be linked together.

Comment: @PSkocik: 1) @Person did provide example how he is doing this with `_file_name_`, so I'm keeping this convention. 2) `extern unsigned char a[]; extern int a_len;` and pipe xxd output to cpp file if needed. Just use imagination.

Comment: @Dawid this still isn't working for me. Will xxd work with files other than binaries?

Comment: @Dawid just tried it with a non binary and it works perfectly. What's going on?

Comment: Can you provide code and binary? I will take a look. (please update question)

Comment: @Dawid Ok, I've put my code and a link to the binary file (it's an exe) that i'm using in my latest edit.

Comment: "Isn't working" is a useless thing to say, @Person. It tells us precisely nothing about what you see.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In the resulting file I see `MZ�`

Comment: I don't see why. And you're still being incredibly vague.

Comment: @Person the output way is incorrect. You need to write one character at a time, eg.
`for (const auto& c : ncat_exe) ofile << c; // if c++11`
or
`for (unsigned long i = 0 ; i < ncat_exe_len; ++i) 
    ofile << ncat_exe[i];`

This is because of how works operator<< for strings - it outputs characters until it find char like '\0' or '\10'.

Comment: The second example worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When your program starts, check if the file exists and is correct.  If it is not present or incorrect, write out the contents of the file from a variable ( structure ) to the file you want.

Comment: The file I need is another binary. Copying that into a variable would be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

string OUTPUT_NAME = "output.txt";

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool writing = false;
    string line;

    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open(OUTPUT_NAME);
    ifstream ifile (argv[0]);
    if (ifile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(ifile, line)) {
            if (writing) {
                ofile << line << endl;
            } else if (line == "--") {
                writing = true;
            }
        }
    }
    ofile.close();
}
```

To create the final binary, copy the *original* binary, then type `echo -e "\n--" >> _binary_name_` and then `cat _file_name_ >> _binary_name_`

Comment: @JeffS: Not for self-answers. This is clearly explained on [the relevant help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I don't see how this works. You're corrupting your binary. No?

Comment: Yes, he is marking end of executable code by `"--"` and then appending binary as raw data at the end of file. Then in runtime his reading binary itself and after the `--` mark dumping content to output. Quite clever.